# Variable assignment: int x = x = 1

Tags: java

This is allowed by the Java compiler, what is it doing?

```
int x = x = 1;
```

I realize that x is assigned to x, but how can it have two `=`s?

Comment: Did you compile it? Than you know the answer to the first question without asking us

Comment: Eclipse says that x is being set to x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

x = 1 both assigns the value 1 to x and also 'returns' 1, it allows for things like this:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
```

Comment: P.S. In java, that sort of thing is considered a code smell in most situations - the only time it's sometimes OK (depends on who you talk to) is similar to the example above

Answer (score 3):

Read assignment statement from right to left:

Acording to [Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)

> There are 12 assignment operators; all are syntactically
>   right-associative (they group right-to-left). Thus, a=b=c means
>   a=(b=c), which assigns the value of c to b and then assigns the value
>   of b to a.

So,

```
int x = x = 1;
```

is the same as

```
x = (x = 1);
```

then

```
x = 1; x = x;
```

Answer (score 1):

`int x` puts `x` on the stack.

The right hand part `x = 1` assigns 1 to `x`. But this is an *expression* with value 1.

Finally this is re-assigned to `x`.